# Flex 4 - Sending string (such as JSON) using HTTPService

Tags: flex4, httpservice

When I use HTTPService.send(paramter) as a POST request, the web server does not appear to see variable "parameter" if it is a string. The server sees the parameter if it's an Object, but I'm looking to use something like httpservice.send(JSON.encode(object)); Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the actual request objects.

in your service define request objects and post them or send them as get if you please.

Sample code here: http://pastebin.com/ft7QW2vg

Then just call .send on the service.

on the server you can simlpy process if with request.form (Asp)

Failing which why not append it to the url with a binding expression. (you would need to encode it since you would be more or less faking a url or a get behaviour).